# Write pandas.DataFrame to snowflake with snowflake.snowpark

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I need write dataframe to snowflake, by using snowflake.snowpark. I have some pandas.DataFrame, have some transformation (corr matrix, description stats, model output,...), but I cant write it back to my snowflake database. Thanks for help.

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark import table
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StringType

sess = None

print('Connecting...')

cnn_params = {
"account": "eu-west-1",
"user": "user",
"password": 'pass',
"warehouse": "xs",
"database": "demodb",
"schema": "demosch",
"role": "ACCOUNTADMIN"
}

try:
    print('session...')
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    sess = Session.builder.configs(cnn_params).create()
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    #print(df.describe())
    
    df.describe().write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("describe_output", table_type="temporary")
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if sess:
        sess.close()
        print('connection closed...')
print('done.')
```

My output:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'
connection closed...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a Pandas dataframe. You need a Snowflake dataframe to write back to the database. See example 3 in the Snowflake documentation for [create a Snowflake dataframe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.html#snowflake-snowpark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `session.write_pandas(df)` to write the pandas dataframe to a Snowflake table, or you can create a Snowpark dataframe using `create_dataframe` and then use `.write.mode...`